# ¿Cómo separar valores por un solo guion si tengo varios?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, tidyverse, dplyr

Tengo el siguiente `data.frame` en RStudio:

```
             mix total
60   ACTA2-FGFR2   221
61    ACTA2-FLNA   221
62     ACTA2-FN1   221
63     ACTA2-FTL   221
64   ACTA2-GABRP   221
65   ACTA2-GAPDH   221
66   ACTA2-GSTP1   221
67   ACTA2-HLA-A   221
68   ACTA2-HLA-B   221
69   ACTA2-HLA-C   221
70 ACTA2-HLA-DRA   221
71   ACTA2-HLA-E   221
```

He separado la columna mix con el siguiente código:

```
basal_sep_09s <- basal_sep_09 %>% 
  separate(mix, into = c('source', 'target'), sep = '-')
```

Donde le indico que me separe en dos columnas la columna mix, con los header como 'source' y 'target' siempre que estén separados por el guion (-). Lo que ocurrió es que del `data.frame` original al haber encontrado valores (mix) con más de un guion, me ha entregado el siguiente `data.frame`:

```
   source target total
60  ACTA2  FGFR2   221
61  ACTA2   FLNA   221
62  ACTA2    FN1   221
63  ACTA2    FTL   221
64  ACTA2  GABRP   221
65  ACTA2  GAPDH   221
66  ACTA2  GSTP1   221
67  ACTA2    HLA   221
68  ACTA2    HLA   221
69  ACTA2    HLA   221
70  ACTA2    HLA   221
71  ACTA2    HLA   221
```

Donde se puede ver que para las filas desde las 67 a la 71 no se puede diferenciar, respecto al `data.frame` original.

Es por ello que pido la ayuda de ¿como mejorar este código para que solo reconozca el primer guion solamente?

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano

Atte.
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer, es separar en tres columnas, para luego juntar las dos últimas:

```
library(tidyverse)

basal_sep_09 %>% 
  separate(mix, 
           into = c('source', 'target', 'other'), 
           sep = '-') %>% 
  mutate(target=ifelse(!is.na(other),
                       paste(target, other, sep="-"),
                       target)) %>% 
 select(source, target)

   source  target
60  ACTA2   FGFR2
61  ACTA2    FLNA
62  ACTA2     FN1
63  ACTA2     FTL
64  ACTA2   GABRP
65  ACTA2   GAPDH
66  ACTA2   GSTP1
67  ACTA2   HLA-A
68  ACTA2   HLA-B
69  ACTA2   HLA-C
70  ACTA2 HLA-DRA
71  ACTA2   HLA-E
Warning message:
Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 7 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].
```

El `warning` en este caso puede ignorarse.